# Oracle SQL statement to create temp table with values from stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a temp table that is created by looping through a table of numbers and then adding values to the the temp table that pass a stored procedure check.

If this was C# I would write the following:

```
    List<string> tempString = new List<string>;

    foreach(var order in OrderList.Orders)
    {
        if (ShipOrder(order) == true)
           tempString.Add(order.OrderId);
    }
```

Or maybe pseudo code would be a better explanation.

Loop through each order in a table of orders. For each order that the stored procedure ShipOrder returns true for add to a temp table of OrdersToShip. Later use the table of OrdersToShip to do an update.

Please note this is a simple version of what I am doing. The procedure to determine if something should be shipped is rather complicated.

Comment: I don't see how this code creates a table.  You need to edit the question and provide more detail

Comment: Is "table of numbers" a table or a collection? What is "pass a store procedure"? Creating and populating tables are two different things - it looks like you want to insert rows into a table (which can be a GTT if you want, but it makes no difference to the question). Can you not do that with a single INSERT statement?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL knows no boolean data type, so your function ShipOrder will have to return something else, maybe numbers 1/0 or strings 'Y'/'N', 'TRUE'/'FALSE'. Apart from that, you simply want to select order IDs:

To insert rows into an existing table:

```
insert into orders_to_ship (orderid)
select orderid
from orders
where shiporder(orderid) = 'TRUE';
```

Or to create the not yet existing table on-the-fly:

```
create table orders_to_ship as
select orderid
from orders
where shiporder(orderid) = 'TRUE';
```

You see you don't need loops in SQL, because you are just describing the data sets you want. And usually you don't need temporary tables either :-)